# How to remove the side-bar symbol "+ - |" after folding on Vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Like the picture below, I want to remove the "+ - |" symbol on the side bar of Vim when folding. How to do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just set `foldcolumn` to 0. This is the default value.

As it is set to `1` in your Vim, you have to find out who set it to `1`. Execute:

```
:verbose set foldcolumn
```

This displays the value of `foldcolumn` and also prints where it was last set.

Maybe it is enough to reset it in you `vimrc`. Like

```
set foldcolumn=0
```

Comment: Thanks! But when I open the folding, there's another strange symbol. How to remove that?

Comment: Please see the second screenshot in the post.

Comment: @Joeyyy You should create a new question for this.  Stackoverflow, is intended as a question/answer site. So it should be only one question. Sometimes this is annoying, I know.